# JUnitTest on Swing Timer

Tags: java, swing, junit, nullpointerexception

I have this method in one of my classes:

```
...
protected Timer timer;
...
public void pauseResume()
{
    if (this.timer.isRunning()) {
        this.timer.stop();
    }
    else
        this.timer.start();
}
```

And then I am trying to test if this works using JUnit:

```
@Test
public void testPauseMethod()
{
    NewClass class1 = new NewClass();
    class1.pauseResume();
    assertTrue(class1.timer.isRunning());
}
```

The JUnitTest fails at `class1.pauseResume();` and gives me a `NullPointerException`. Anyone knows what the problem is?

Comment: Is `timer` initialized?

Comment: Is it `timer` initialized within `NewClass` constructor? If not then you have the cause of the NPE.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/24100776#24100776

Comment: Oh, it was not. Thanks, is that the normal cause of NPE?

Comment: Thats the only cause of an NPE... when attempt to access something on a null object. The reasons for the object being null vary, but its always because you have a reference to nothing.